# Redirection issue to login page when opening new tab in Laravel 10 application within Docker

Tags: docker, session, redirect, laravel-10

I am working on a Laravel 10 application that functions as an API for an Angular front-end. The application runs smoothly without Docker, but when I run it using Docker, I encounter a redirection issue to the login page (Session expires) when I attempt to open something in a new tab. However, navigating within the same tab works fine. This issue disappears when I serve the application without Docker. How can I resolve this redirection problem when running my Laravel application through Docker?